# Error: No matching constructor found on type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application where I am using multiple forms. There is one main form which gets opened when we start the application which is know as `MainWindow.xaml`. This form then have multiple forms which gets opened depending on the user option. There is a form `StartClassWindow.xaml`. Currently I am working on this form so I want it to start directly instead of `MainWindow.xaml`. So to do this I changed the `app.xaml startupuri`:

```
<Application x:Class="Class.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
         StartupUri="StartClassWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But then it started giving error like below:

> No matching constructor found on type 'Class.StartClassWindow'. You
>   can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this
>   type.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

Here is the `StartClassWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace Class
{
    public partial class StartClassWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {

       public StartClassWindow(string classData)
       {
          InitializeComponent();
          className = classData;
          function();
       }
       //rest of the code.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to add a parameter-less constructor to your `StartClassWindow` like this:

```
public StartClassWindow(string classData)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    className = classData;
    function();
}

public StartClassWindow()
{

}
```

Or if you don't want to have another constructor you can override the [`OnStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the `App.xaml.cs` but you should **remove** the `StartupUri="StartClassWindow.xaml"` in your `App.xaml` first. Like below:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    StartClassWindow st = new StartClassWindow("");
    st.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

"Normally", your constructor must be parameterless:

```
public Login()
```

But, since you are using dependency injection, like this:

```
public Login(IUserService userService)
```

The constructor isn't parameterless, and the framework cannot instantiate the page if it's not told how to.

For this there are a couple of options:

#### Remove service from constructor

Just like this, but you'll need to access the userservice differently:

```
public Login()
```

---

#### pre .net 4.8, 4.7, using Unity (or Prism)

You can use a dependency injection framework like `Unity` to register the components.
It is described here:

https://www.wpftutorial.net/ReferenceArchitecture.html

```
public class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
       
        MainWindow mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

---

#### Manual using Navigation Service

Manually navigate, and do your own construction:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new LoginPage(new UserService);
```

As described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

---

#### .net 5 WPF, using built in DI

If you are using .net 5, here is a tutorial. Make sure to register both the window and the service:

https://executecommands.com/dependency-injection-in-wpf-net-core-csharp/

Here's an example:

```
private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IUserService,UserService>();
    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
}

private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to comment out the Startup and StartupUri

```html
<Application x:Class="Data_Export_Refinity.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <!-- Startup="Application_Startup">
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" -->
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Oh thank, i forgot remove `StartupUri`