# Out-of-debuggers troubles when trying to introduce dependency injection to a WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection

I'm creating a new WPF application and I decide to use both `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` and `Microsoft.DependencyInjection` packages in this project.

I'd tried this in previous projects before and I knew I had to override the method `OnStartUp` in `App.xaml.cs` file like this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<ViewModel.MainVM>();// the viewmodel
    services.AddScoped<MainWindow>();

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var window = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
    window.Show();//Another problem: The MainWindow appeared twice on startup when I added these codes

    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
}
```

And I had a good feeling of the constructor of `MainWindow` class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel.MainVM mainVM;
    public MainWindow(ViewModel.MainVM mainVM)
    {
        this.mainVM = mainVM;
        this.DataContext = mainVM;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The trouble is that the application throws an annoying `System.NullReferenceException` when it ran.It's just like the default WPF framework doesn't work well with `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` or `Microsoft.DependencyInjection` packages (it seems that the constructor of `MainWindow` class with parameters is ignored by program).

The debugger did not load any symbols when the error occurred which made it hard to locate bugs.

However, I had completed several WPF programs and such errors didn't occured. I tried to alter constructor codes but each time the program turned to the non-parameter ones. Is there anything incompatible?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327777/error-no-matching-constructor-found-on-type

Comment: It worked well when I deleted the StartupUri in App.xaml and overrode OnStartup method. We could come to a conclusion that the default startup method of WPF has a bad compatibility with MVVM or dependency injection(I know things like IoC may not  even exist in 2006 when WPF was developed). Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: You may find this useful https://www.nuget.org/packages/Wpf.Extensions.Hosting/1.1.0#readme-body-tab